# Creating a maven project

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

How can I create a simple maven project in eclipse. Every time I create it gives an error while creating the project.

> errors Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type CoreException: Could
>   not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2:
>   ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
>   central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from/to
>   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connect times
>   out   pom.xml /speech-to-text line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle
>   Mapping Problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a standalone Maven installation, take a look at [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) about user settings; if you're behind a firewall/NAT, then you probably need to add proxy definition inside the `<proxy>` tag.

If you use Maven embedded in Eclipse, the sentence above is valid, too, but additionally you need to make sure your user settings file is taken into account (Preferences -> Maven -> User settings).

Answer (score 10):

I've just solved this problem with embedded Maven, thanks to @MaDa.

For other people in the same situation who haven't just been on the journey that I have, try this:

1) Create / update settings.xml. Find out where it should be in Eclipse: Window > Preferences > Maven > User Settings. Browse to the location specified for settings.xml - if it's not there, create it. Add the following:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>1</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>      
      <host>*INSERT PROXY HERE*</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>    
</proxies>

</settings>
```

If you have a settings.xml file, you probably won't need the < settings> tags.

2) Eclipse: Window --> Preferences --> Maven --> Installations. Browse "Global settings for embedded installation" and point to the file settings.xml.

3) Restart Eclipse

...that's it. Hopefully it was less painful than my experience. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to update maven project

1. Go to poroject right click
2. maven
3. Update Project (ALT + F5)

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy? Have you configured it in your settings.xml file?