# How can I create a maven project with standard directory layout?

Tags: java, maven, web

I just want create a maven project with this structure:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: What is your IDE? Looks like IntelliJ. Then just create a Maven project.

Comment: If you're on Linux then you can create the directory structure using `cd /path/to/directories &&
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p -- /path/to/backup/{} \;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a maven project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138099/creating-a-maven-project)

Comment: I know, what if I want my own directory structure?
I mean, I want my project like this: src > main > java, src > main > resources and src > main > webapp.
I think I am confused, just adding pom.xml to my project it becomes a good maven projects? Or need I configure other things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Maven's archetype plugin to create a skeleton project as follows:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart        \
   -DarchetypeVersion=1.1                                  \
   -DgroupId=com.company                                   \
   -DartifactId=project                                    \
   -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT                                  \
   -Dpackage=com.company.project
```

Comment: I know, what if I want my own directory structure?
I mean, I want my project like this: src > main > java, src > main > resources and src > main > webapp.
I think I am confused, just adding pom.xml to my project it becomes a good maven projects? Or need I configure other things?

Comment: Maven devotees would tell you you should stick with the convention and I agree.  But if you really want to have your own directory structure you can look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333964/how-to-edit-the-directory-structure-in-maven which tells how to set your own source and other directory locations.  Other people who use maven and look at your stuff will not like this :-)